# Karaites in Australia?

Tags: non-rabbinic-judaism

I’m interested in Karaism, but from what I can tell, there are none in my native Australia. I’m not planning on visiting the Bay Area.

Does anybody know who and where the Karites are in this country?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Benjamin! While this is a fine question, be aware that there are no regular users here who are karaite, so you likely won't get many useful answers.

Comment: Why would anyone think that this is off topic? Jews not Judaism? Seems on topic to me.

Answer (score 1):

[The Jewish Virtual Library](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/karaites) shows no awareness of Karaites in Australia, for in the concluding paragraph of its article on the sect it states:

> According to the Karaites,
>   this movement at one time attracted as much as 40 percent of the
>   Jewish people. Today, Karaites are a very small minority, and most
>   Rabbinical Jews do not even know that they exist. A Karaite community
>   existed in Egypt until the Six Day War. A somewhat sizable community
>   still lives in Los Angeles.

*Encyclopedia.com*, on the other hand, has a more scholarly article by Sumi Cooligan and more precise demographics indicating that there are some in Australia, though no number or location or synagogue name is given:

> The population figures on Karaites in Israel are not exact because, for both political and religious reasons, the Karaites do not allow themselves to be counted. Population estimates range from 8,000 to 25,000. Approximately 1,000 Karaites of Egyptian origin live in the United States. Significantly smaller numbers are scattered in other countries, including Canada, France, Switzerland, [Turkey], England, Brazil, and Australia.